# What is the use of BindingServiceConfiguration.inputBindingLifecycle() method in Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I would like to know the use of BindingServiceConfiguration.inputBindingLifecycle() method in Spring Cloud Stream(for Kafka), and the possible business scenarios this method helps?

Answer (score 0):

It's used by the framework to `start()` the binding when the app is ready to start and `stop()` it when the app is shut down.

It's not really intended for user code to invoke it, especially with Kafka, because stopping it will cause a rebalance of the partitions.

It would be better to use the actuator to pause/resume if you want to stop receiving messaged for a while (while not allowing the partitions to be given to another instance).